# Edit html/css of iframe contents

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a simple filebrowser set up for our intranet site.  I used an Iframe to link it to a folder where some of our HR files are.  My question is can I edit how that looks by any chance or is there an easier way to program it? I just wnat to be able to point to a folder on the server and the folders/files show up so that internal users can access the needed pdf, xls, doc files.  It looks currenty like a directory of a folder if you were to type in C:\Program Files in your web browser.  Thanks

Comment: are you using local host in the company ? or the website is online ? is there any code ?

Comment: If these files are on another server, I believe you cannot do that directly through the iframe. But you might be able to create a php page that will [list all the files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), and style them as you wish.

Comment: This one we host yes.  The code is: <iframe src="http://172.16.100.156/content/employee_Forms/" height="500" width="500"></iframe> which just looks like the same thing as if you were to put C:/Program Files in your web browser.. didn't know if there was a way to style that

Comment: there is a file manager framework called EL-Finder . Just have a look at it .

Comment: Yeah I saw EL Finder.. didnt know if anyone had used it and had any luck?